# Вопрос по pickerView и Label

Tags: objective-c, xcode, label

Добрый день!
Не мог сделать штуку с     pickerView, идея в том что выбранное значение должно отбражаться в Label и по нажатию на кнопку начинаться обратный отчет.
лейбл:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *roundText;
```

массив:

```
 NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int j = 1; j < 16; j++) {

    [arr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",j]];
}
self.a = [NSArray arrayWithArray:arr];
```

кнопка

```
- (IBAction)goButtonPressed:(id)sender {


NSMutableCharacterSet *с = self.а[/* что тут надо? */];{
    NSLog(@"index = %@",с);
}
```

Comment: так в чем вопрос? надо отобразить в label или начать отсчет?

Comment: вообще и то и другое, но для начала отобразить, с отсчетом вроде почти сделал.

Comment: сделать себя делегатом и в методе `- pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` смотреть значение соответствующего ряда в массиве и присваивать его в label

Comment: немного не понимаю, как смотреть значение соответствующего ряда в массиве и присваивать его в label. извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, просто не могу этого сделать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Грубо говоря примерно так это будет выглядеть

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) UIPickerView *picker;
@property (nonatomic) UILabel *label;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *dataSourceArray;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.dataSourceArray = @[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5"];

    self.picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];
    self.picker.dataSource = self;
    self.picker.delegate = self; //назначаете себя делегатом
    [self.view addSubview:self.picker];

    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 300, 320, 100)];

    //если надо присвоить в label начальное значение пикера
    self.label.text = self.dataSourceArray[0];
    [self.view addSubview:self.label];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return self.dataSourceArray.count;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return self.dataSourceArray[row];
}

//каждый раз, когда значение пикера меняется, вызывается этот метод
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    self.label.text = self.dataSourceArray[row]; //меняете значение label
}

@end
```

Comment: галочку не забудьте )

Comment: объявление вью контроллера должно выглядеть так: MyViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

Comment: @implementation MyViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate> все равно не помогает.

Comment: а вы догадались объявить все переменные, которые присутствуют в примере?

Comment: добавил в ответ весь код для класса